# ValueError: malformed node or string

Tags: python, valueerror, malformed

Why do I get this error message: `ValueError: malformed node or string` when I pass data in the below format into the "parse_webhook" function?

Thanks!

```py
webhook_data = {"side": "BUY","key": "8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325"}

def parse_webhook(webhook_data):

    """
    :param webhook_data: POST data from tradingview, as a string.
    :return: Dictionary version of string.
    """

    data = ast.literal_eval(webhook_data)
    return data
```

Wrror I get:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))

ValueError: malformed node or string: {'side': 'BUY', 'key': '8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325'}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? `ast.literal_eval` takes a string and return the python evaluated object, here you alreart have the object which is a dict. It would work for the string `'{"side": "BUY","key": "8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325"}'`

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval/68732605#68732605

Comment: in my case, I was already passing a string. Problem was the string had some `null`s in it. Fixed by `ast.literal_eval(my_str.replace("null", "None"))`

Answer (score 18):

## `ast.literal.eval`:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
> string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
> only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

You can't pass a dictionary to [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast%20literal_eval#ast.literal_eval). It only takes a string input and converts it into appropriate python object. You can't pass lists / dictionary / tuples, etc to the `ast.literal_eval` .

---

### Use Case:

The following snippet would have been a valid use of this method -

```py
import ast
# Converting a string representation of dictionary into dictionary.
webhook_data = ast.literal_eval('{"side": "BUY","key": "8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325"}')
print(webhook_data)
```

**Output:**

```json
{'side': 'BUY', 'key': '8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325'}
```

You could also use it when you have a list, tuple, booleans, numbers, sets etc in form of string and this method would evaluate it into appropriate python object.

---

### Possible Fix to Error:

You already have a dictionary constructed with you. You could make your code work by doing the following edit:

```py
webhook_data = {"side": "BUY","key": "8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325"}

def parse_webhook(webhook_data):

    """
    :param webhook_data: POST data from tradingview, as a string.
    :return: Dictionary version of string.
    """

    data = ast.literal_eval(str(webhook_data))
    return data
```

But the above code would just be redundant. You are just converting a dictionary to string using `str()` and that converted string back into dictionary using a `ast.literal_eval`.

---

**NOTE:**

1. It is possible to crash the Python interpreter with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler.
2. `ast.literal_eval` raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not.

Answer (score 5):

`ast.literal_eval()` expects a string. Convert `webhook_data` to string with `str()` and it will work.

```py
webhook_data = {"side": "BUY","key": "8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325"}

def parse_webhook(webhook_data):

    """
    :param webhook_data: POST data from tradingview, as a string.
    :return: Dictionary version of string.
    """

    data = ast.literal_eval(str(webhook_data)) # this fixes the issue
    return data
```

---

```py
print(parse_webhook(webhook_data))
```

**Output:**

```json
{'side': 'BUY', 'key': '8234023409fa3242309sdfasdf903024917325'}
```

Comment: This does not work.