# malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.BinOp object at 0x10f5c5f00> when remove ' of words in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to remove the start ' and end ' of a string in Python 3, this is how I do it:

```
new_words = ast.literal_eval(str(words))
```

but when the content is `W/"128d6ff6070c2313a28f27f367f2a412"`, (BTW: another content works fine) some special throw this error, this code shows error:

```
malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.BinOp object at 0x1222875b0>
```

this is the minimal reproduce function like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    words = 'W/"128d6ff6070c2313a28f27f367f2a412"'
    new_words = ast.literal_eval(str(words))
    print(new_words)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix it? I have read this question: [ValueError: malformed node or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478834/valueerror-malformed-node-or-string). And my string was not a json, I also tried to convert the content to str, but still did not fixed it. What is the rubust way to remove the start ' and end ' of a word in Python 3? The desire output is:

```
W/"128d6ff6070c2313a28f27f367f2a412"
```

sometimes the word contains ' in the start or end, I need to remove it. This is the real code of project, the rss source etag was dynamic:

```
    @staticmethod
    def update_last_modified(source, etag: str, last_modified):
        with session_scope() as local_session:
            try:
                new = local_session.query(RssSource).filter(RssSource.id == source.id).first()
                if StringUtils.not_empty(etag):
                    # remove the string start & end "
                    new.etag = ast.literal_eval(str(etag))
                new.last_modified = last_modified
                local_session.commit()
            except SQLAlchemyError as e:
                local_session.rollback()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("update session failed", e)
                local_session.rollback()
            finally:
                local_session.close()
```

Comment: What is your expected/desired output? Your example string doesn't contain any `'` characters?

Comment: I have added the desire output. @IainShelvington

Comment: You just want to print the string? Wouldn't `print(words)` do? Not sure what you mean by removing the `'` chars as there aren't any in the string

Comment: I want to remove the ' before print the string, I don't want the string like this `'W/"128d6ff6070c2313a28f27f367f2a412"`. @IainShelvington

Comment: The string doesn't contain any `'` chars, just `print(words)` will print your desired output...

Comment: the words was dynamic, there just an example. @IainShelvington

Comment: If the string has a `'` at the start or end you want to remove it? Something like `print(words.strip("'"))`?